# What is the sugested way to upgrade 20.04 kernel to v5.6?

Tags: kernel, 20.04

As I have similar [problem as had Vladymir](https://askubuntu.com/q/1199496/10577), I wanted to use his solution to upgrade to 5.6 kernel. After little lookup I found that for 20.04 in official repos are 4 oem (?) (signed or unsigned) 5.6 kernel images:

```
linux-image-5.6.0-1007-oem - Signed kernel image oem
linux-image-5.6.0-1008-oem - Signed kernel image oem
linux-image-5.6.0-1010-oem - Signed kernel image oem
linux-image-5.6.0-1011-oem - Signed kernel image oem
```

I did not found any 5.6 generic images. I have no idea, how affects me oem and I have no idea what are meaning those numbers before `-oem`, but I just want to install 5.6 kernel for my desktop? Are those kernels meant to install for general use on desktop? Or what is the proper way to install generic 5.6 kernel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the Kernels for Ubuntu in this website, there are many: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

Before you start to install a new kernel, it is recommended to backup all of your data.

For example if you want kernel 5.6.10 then you need to download these files:

```
linux-headers-5.6.10-050610_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_all.deb

linux-headers-5.6.10-050610-generic_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_amd64.deb

linux-image-unsigned-5.6.10-050610-generic_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_amd64.deb

linux-modules-5.6.10-050610-generic_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_amd64.deb
```

After you downloaded the files, just run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you, I looked more official way, being aware of PPAs, it seemed strange, that threre are available just some oem-kernels, whatever they may be...

Answer (score 0):

The kernels you listed can be installed on desktop machines for general use. You can find more information about the Ubuntu OEM kernel on this [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel). The number before `-oem` is the build number, the higher the number, the newer the kernel.

Comment: As Linux user more than 20 years, I am used to see on Debian/Ubuntu kernels with `-generic`-postfix after version (for generic version, of course). But now I was surprised, that in official repo were no `-generic` kernels, same time there were oem's (which in this context seemed really obscure: what should be "Original equipment manufacturer" kernel ;) Thank you for the info, my question was badly worded, emphasis of my thought was more on "where are my generic-kernels disappeared???"